# Searching for an UI Element of google maps

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I'm looking for an UI element that can be found in the google maps app.
When we start the google application we can load indoor maps.
When we are watching an indoor map small buttons with floorlevels are displayed 
on the right side of the screen. If we click on such a button we switch to the chosen floorlevel.

How is this UI element called and how can I implement such an UI element?

//Edit:
Here the image: (right image, right side)
[image: Google Maps picture]

Greets
mister-viper

Comment: try to add some image, to let us know what you're talking about

Comment: done :) (Have a look on the right side of the right picture (floor level 1-4))

Comment: afais there is no image, just vertical layout with numbers, left border and some blue dot. It isn't built-in UI element, you'll have to build it on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would appear to be a vertical `LinearLayout` holding a series of `TextView` widgets, using two different backgrounds (one transparent to show the LinearLayout's own background, plus one for the selected layer), plus an `ImageView` for the blue dot (visible for the selected layer, invisible for the other layers).